# How to capture return value from Netezza stored procedure into a variable?

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

I'll be grateful if someone point me to the correct way to capture Netezza stored procedure return value into a variable.

```
create or replace procedure test() returns varchar(10) language nzplsql as
begin
 return "success";
end;
```

and then something like(in another procedure)

```
var_name := call test();
```

to capture "success" into variable `var_name`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the difference here is including the word "Call" in the syntax causes NZPLSQL to discard the results of the Proc Call. [(ref)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_calling_another_proc.html)

so instead of

```
var_name := call test();
```

you just want

```
var_name := test();
```

Note: if you want more than one value returned you should review the below documentation describing using reftable.

[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.nz.sproc.doc%2Fc_sproc_returning_a_result_set.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_returning_a_result_set.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please find 2 procedures below where return value from first procedure is being capture by second procedure -

Procedure VarunTest -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE varunTest()
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL RETURNS varchar(255) AS

BEGIN_PROC

DECLARE

BEGIN
        return 'varunTest';

END;


END_PROC;
```

Create procedure

```
\i varunTest.sql
```

Procedure BajajTest

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bajajTest()
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL RETURNS varchar(255) AS

BEGIN_PROC

DECLARE
 v_test varchar;

BEGIN
 v_test := varuntest();

 raise notice 'result => %', v_test;

END;


END_PROC;
```

Create Procedure

```
\i bajajTest.sql
```

Calling the procedure

```
call bajajTest();
```

Result of procedure -

```
NOTICE:  result => varunTest
BAJAJTEST
-----------

(1 row)
```

Hope this will help you. :)